How to use llm models downloaded with ollama with llama.cpp?
I'm considering switching from Ollama to llama.cpp, but I have a question before making the move. I've already downloaded several LLM models using Ollama, and I'm working with a low-speed internet connection. Can I directly use these models with llama.cpp, or will I need to re-download them?
I was expecting that the models might be in a standard format that could be used across different platforms, which would save me the time and data required to re-download them.
Thanks for your help!

When Ollama downloads a model and its additional layers, it saves them under files with SHA-256 values as their names. You can simply point to the SHA value that represents the model, like this:
/opt/llama.cpp/bin/llama-bench -m /data/models/ollama/models/blobs/sha256-87048bcd55216712ef14c11c2c303728463207b165bf18440b9b84b07ec00f87

Note that model files implicitly use the .gguf or .ggml extension. Other files may implicitly have a .json, .txt, or other text-based extensions.
When I list the relevant folder, I see the following:
$ ls -l <path_to_ollama_data_location>/ollama/models/blobs/
total 14490048
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       8433 Aug 27 18:17 sha256-097a36493f718248845233af1d3fefe7a303f864fae13bc31a3a9704229378ca
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        136 Aug 27 18:17 sha256-109037bec39c0becc8221222ae23557559bc594290945a2c4221ab4f303b8871
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        487 Aug 27 18:17 sha256-10aa81da732eae8a66e07d70620089a608f546ff280a2856a43be69d622f715a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4108916992 Aug  9 13:49 sha256-170370233dd5c5415250a2ecd5c71586352850729062ccef1496385647293868
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         65 Aug 27 18:17 sha256-2490e7468436707d5156d7959cf3c6341cc46ee323084cfa3fcf30fe76e397dc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      11356 Aug  9 13:49 sha256-43070e2d4e532684de521b885f385d0841030efa2b1a20bafb76133a5e1379c1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         96 Aug  6 00:34 sha256-56bb8bd477a519ffa694fc449c2413c6f0e1d3b1c88fa7e3c9d88d3ae49d4dcb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  624434368 Aug  9 13:49 sha256-72d6f08a42f656d36b356dbe0920675899a99ce21192fd66266fb7d82ed07539
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        564 Aug  9 13:49 sha256-7c658f9561e5dbbafb042a00f6a4de57877adddd957809111f3123e272632b4d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4661211808 Aug  6 00:34 sha256-87048bcd55216712ef14c11c2c303728463207b165bf18440b9b84b07ec00f87
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       1692 Aug  6 00:34 sha256-8cf247399e57085e6b34c345ebea38c1aa3e2b25c8294eecb746dd7b01dd9079
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         67 Aug  9 13:49 sha256-c43332387573e98fdfad4a606171279955b53d891ba2500552c2984a6560ffb4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        485 Aug  6 00:34 sha256-e711233e734332fe5f8a09b2407fb5a083e39ca7e0ba90788026414cd4c059af
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         30 Aug  9 13:49 sha256-ed11eda7790d05b49395598a42b155812b17e263214292f7b87d15e14003d337
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      12321 Aug  6 00:34 sha256-f1cd752815fcf68c3c2e73b2b00b5396c5dffb9eebe49567573f275f9ec85fcd

The three large files correspond to four models I have downloaded:
$ ollama list
NAME            ID              SIZE    MODIFIED
gemma2:latest   ff02c3702f32    5.4 GB  2 weeks ago
llava:latest    8dd30f6b0cb1    4.7 GB  5 weeks ago
llama3.1:latest 62757c860e01    4.7 GB  5 weeks ago

The smaller files are typically text-based layers used by the Ollama server. For example:
$ cat <path_to_ollama_data_location>/ollama/models/blobs/sha256-109037bec39c0be
cc8221222ae23557559bc594290945a2c4221ab4f303b8871
<start_of_turn>user
{{ if .System }}{{ .System }} {{ end }}{{ .Prompt }}<end_of_turn>
<start_of_turn>model
{{ .Response }}<end_of_turn>

